# How to fix Joomla site both frontend and backend shows error page (site down) after fix database?

Tags: joomla-3.4, database, error-pages, fatal-error

I have Joomla 3.4.8 site (multilingual site) that shows this error on the front-end that said :

`**Fatal error:** Call to undefined method JLanguageMultilang::getSiteLangs() in **/mysite/public_html/administrator/components/com_languages/helpers/multilangstatus.php** on line **88**"`

And on the back-end it show this error :

`Error displaying the error page: Invalid JDocument Class: Invalid JDocument Class`

It happens after I went to Extension > Manage > Database > Fix.

So how to fix this? I thought this is database issue. But I got no clue how to start or resolve it. I couldn't enter both frontend and backend. So my site completely down :(

And I only have back up from Akeeba which I couldn't access because I couldn't reach my back-end.

**Info**: When I use Firefox Inspector Tool it shows this error :

`The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.`

I don't know this would be useful information or not, before I fix the database, I do updating my Joomla from 3.4.8 to 3.5, but it failed. And from this link https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Updating_from_an_existing_version, I clear my browser cache. Then run fix database.

Comment: Does the backup you have from Akeeba include both the files and database (Default Backup Profile)?

Comment: @MichaelYaeger haha, i forgot, more than half year though. All I can recall, I restore my joomla site using softaculous backup file from cpanel. Seems I messed the database, when doing update from 3.4.8 to 3.5. And I couldnt update it again, because of it. It will makes database more messing, and again the same error occure. (i can clarify this because I did once update it again after restoring the backup).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an Akeeba backup, I would use their Akeeba Kickstart offering to restore the server.

Akeeba Kickstart is a downloadable ZIP file which when uploaded to the server along with the JPA backup file, can be accessed via the web to do a stand alone restore.

The application will restore the full database and website file structure.  I recommend doing a test run locally to familiarize yourself with the process and confirm the backup is good.

If that work, then repeat the process in your server.

[Akeeba Backup - Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html)

Comment: Sorry, finally I have time to report it to you. After restoring, My Joomla version become 3.4.6. And when I go to Extension, manage database, the database become more messed up. It says something like the joomla version didn't match with the version stored in database/table. So I fix the database again, and, my site became blank again. Oh, I'm really suck with database, worrying if I would be make it worse. Update to 3.5 isn't easy. And some extension have not ready yet for 3.5. I'm stuck with this one.

Comment: Sounds like after effects of a failed upgrade to me. Successfully upgrading and doing fix database probably fixes it. I forget the location (sorry), but Joomla keeps the sql files it uses to update the database on upgrade somewhere and then uses those to "fix database", you might want to check if that has sql files for wrong Joomla versions (>3.4.6). After you remove those fix database should work. Kind of... it should no longer break your site.

Comment: If you have wrong sql files you might also have incorrect versions of PHP files for Joomla and its components. That can be tricky to fix.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in case of a failed upgrade you can check out this tutorial to manual upgrade a Joomla Installation.

> https://gist.github.com/mbabker/d7bfb4e1e2fbc6b7815a733607f89281

It sometimes helps to get out of failed upgrade or at least bring access back to your administrator interface.

This method has been referenced by the community when having trouble with a failed upgrade or when having no other way to update your Joomla (Method C)

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Upgrading_from_Joomla_3.4.x_to_3.5